# Compare with do/while a onView().check() on android JUnit test

Tags: android, junit, do-while

I need to make a comparison like this:

```
do{
      onView(withText("Some Text 1")).perform(swipeUp());
   }while (onView(withText("Some Text 2")).check(matches(isCompletelyDisplayed())) == false);
```

But this function don't return a boolean, how can I compare this to make the `swipeUp()`?

**EDIT**

I use this:

```
     do {
            try {
                onView(withText("Some text 1")).check(matches((isCompletelyDisplayed())));

                control = 0;

            } catch (NoMatchingViewException e) {
                onView(withText("Some text 2")).perform(swipeUp());
                control = 1;
            }
        }while (control == 1);
```

And the error now is:

> android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler$AssertionFailedWithCauseError: 'at least 100 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.' doesn't match the selected view.
>
> Expected: at least 100 percent of the view's area is displayed to the user.
>
> Got: "AppCompatTextView{id=16908310, res-name=title, visibility=VISIBLE, width=667, height=86, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=64.0, text=Check app permissions, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}"